# Unable to login when using the MediaWiki API

Tags: python, mediawiki-api

I would like create new user accounts in my local MediaWiki using the MediaWiki API using a simply Python script.

Based on the [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Account_creation), it is my understanding that I must first [login](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login#Python) as an administrator to have the privilege needed for the user creation.

I use some code like this to login:

```py
import requests

def login(base_url: str):
    session = requests.Session()

    url = base_url + "/api.php"

    # Retrieve login token first
    print(f"Get login token...")
    response = session.get(url=url, params={
        'action':"query",
        'meta':"tokens",
        'type':"login",
        'format':"json"
    })
    data = response.json()
    login_token = data['query']['tokens']['logintoken']
    print(f"login_token={login_token}")

    print(f"Login...")
    response = requests.post(url, data={
        'action': 'login',
        'lgname': 'admin',
        'lgpassword': 'admin_password',
        'lgtoken': login_token,
        'format': 'json',
    })
    login_data = response.json()
    print(login_data)
```

where `admin` is the administrator account I specified during the original configuration of MediaWiki.

Unfortunately the result is `{'login': {'result': 'Failed', 'reason': 'Unable to continue login. Your session most likely timed out.'}}`.

What am I missing or how can I debug this problem?

Comment: Change `requests.post` to `session.post`. It seems that each token is session-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrowly, the problem is that you are using `requests.post` instead of `session.post` (so you lose the session, as pointed out by the error message). But what you really want to do is create an [owner-only OAuth 2 app](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth/Owner-only_consumers) with the `Create accounts` grant, and then add the `Authorization` header to the API requests you make.

If the wiki does not support OAuth, you should use a [bot password](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Bot_passwords); that will use the same login flow as in the question, but it's more robust (bot password logins are guaranteed to work via the `login` API endpoint, normal logins aren't). Plus, you won't have to store a sensitive password along with the bot code.